# Is it legal for Bill Gates to hire a foreign ambassador to kill a terrorist for him?

Tags: international, murder, diplomatic-immunity

Is it legal for Bill Gates to hire a foreign ambassador (for example, the Prime Minister of Kazakhstan) to kill a terrorist for him?

For example, the terrorist could actually be trying to kill his family, maybe the Russian Prime Minister, or a dissident lawyer in Russia.

Comment: Why downvote a philosopher's question in law ethnics?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question is unclear and is exacerbated by poor English.

Comment: @feetwet which part you don't understand?

Comment: @feetwet:  I've tried to improve the English for Victor ...

Comment: Also, a foreign politician (such as a Prime Minister) doesn't actually enjoy diplomatic immunity. That only applies to diplomats.  A Head of State (President, King) may enjoy immunity as Head of State, but a Prime Minister is usually Head of Government, but not Head of State.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking three separate questions, each without any context.  Is this really a question about Bill Gates?  Or do you mean "any wealthy American?"  What points of the question do you think might make murder for hire *not* illegal?  In the second paragraph: the terrorist is trying to kill *whose* family?  And the terrorist *is* a Russian?  How does that matter?  Third paragraph: Now you're asking about a lawyer killing Bill Gates in an accident?  What is the legal question there?

Comment: Bill Gates isn't the one with diplomatic immunity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It is illegal to hire someone to kill someone else.  Even if the killer enjoys diplomatic immunity, the person hiring the killer has committed a crime.

As to your last paragraph, that is properly a separate question, but the answer is that they can't do it because murder is illegal.

Comment: The goal of **diplomatic immunity** is to prevent possible *molesting* of the diplomat while performing his diplomatic tasks. Upon return, the diplomat can face charges for any commited criminal activities by his own country.